# How to call Firebase cloud function with raw JSON?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase cloud function `checkUsers`. Which works in postman like the screenshot attached.

This is the cloud function

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {

  if (req.body.emails === undefined) {
    res.status(422).send("Missing email addresses input");
    return;
  }

  const emailsToCheck = req.body.emails;
  if (emailsToCheck.length == 0) {
    res.status(422).send("No email addresses provided");
    return;
  }

  var existingEmails = [];
  var emailsChecked = [];
  listAllUsers(function(page) {
    page.forEach(function(record) {
      existingEmails.push(record.toJSON()["email"].toLowerCase());
    });
  }, function(lastPage) {
    // Here, we should have all the users
    lastPage.forEach(function(record) {
      existingEmails.push(record.toJSON()["email"].toLowerCase());
    });

    // Iterating over emailsToCheck and checking if the email is in existingEmails
    emailsToCheck.forEach(function(record) {
      const exists = existingEmails.includes(record);
      emailsChecked.push({ email: record, exists: exists });
    });

    res.status(200).send(emailsChecked);
  });
});

exports.checkUsers = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

[image: POSTMAN Request example]

When I try to call the same function from iOS SDK, it does not work.

```
func checkEmails(
    _ contacts: [SIContact],
    _ completion: @escaping (([SIContact]) -> Void)
  ) {
    let data = ["aaa", "akshit.zaveri@gmail.com", "bbb"]
    let params = ["emails": data]
    self.functions.httpsCallable("checkUsers").call(params) { (result, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error while checking emails \(error)")
        return completion(contacts)
      }

      guard let results = result?.data as? [[String: Any]] else {
        return completion(contacts)
      }

      print(results)
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I am getting 422, Missing email addresses input error. That should be only returned if the emails parameter is not found in the request, as we can see in the cloud function code above.

I have tried to debug it, and my conclusion is the iOS code is not passing the emails array properly.

Comment: Can you please share the code of your Cloud Function. Also which error do you get?

Comment: "it does not work" is not enough information.  Please edit the question to show the backend code and explain what you've done to debug the request.  Include logs, errors, and expected output.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) with [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  They work differently.  You can't use the Firebase SDK for callable function to invoke some HTTP endpoint.  If you want to invoke an HTTP endpoint, you will need to use an HTTP library for your platform.